# Prove there are exactly three solution

Tags: nonlinear-system, bifurcation

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872598/solving-equation-a-x-log-x-log-a-0/873826#873826) question, the OP asked to find the solutions of:
$$a^{−x}+{\log x \over \log a}=0$$
In my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/873826/28743), I showed that when $a<e^e$ there can be at most one solution. It is also clear that any solution must lie in $x\in[0,1]$.

**How can one prove that there exactly three solutions for all $a>e^e$?**

Comment: An interesting follow up. (The thing I was curious myself about was, given that one could write it in the fixed-point form $x=a^{-a^{-x}}$, could one look for interesting chaotic dynamics owing to the appearance of the pitchfork.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $\alpha = \log a > e$ and $f(x) = a^{-x} + \frac{\log x}{\log a} = e^{-\alpha x} + \frac{1}{\alpha} \log x$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= -\infty \\
f(1/\alpha) &= \frac{1}{e} - \frac{\log \alpha}{\alpha} > 0 \\
f(1/e) &= \frac{1}{e^{\alpha/e}} - \frac{1}{\alpha} < 0\\
f(1) &= e^{-\alpha} > 0
\end{align*}
(using the fact that $x < e^x -1$ for positive $x$ in the estimate for $f(1/e)$). Thus $f$ has at least three zeros.

The derivative
$$f'(x) = - \alpha e^{-\alpha x} + \frac{1}{\alpha x}$$
vanishes exactly at $x = -\frac{1}{\alpha} W(-\frac{1}{\alpha})$, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$-function. Since $\alpha > e$, there are (despite the notation) two such $x$, which implies that $f$ has at most three zeros.